# AppleScript : convert decimal to hours / days

Tags: applescript

How can I convert the value on my script from decimal to hours / or day?

For converting decimal to hour I believe it's :

> hours + (minutes /60)

but my variable is in this format :

> 23.498611111111

Somehow I have to get 23 set as a value (hours) and same for the two decimal after the "." but I'm not sure how to proceed

here is my full script:

```
set myVariableDateHere to "25/03/2019 00:00:00"
set myWantedDate to convertDate(myVariableDateHere)

to convertDate(textDate)
    set resultDate to the current date

    set the day of resultDate to (text 1 thru 2 of textDate)
    set the month of resultDate to (text 4 thru 5 of textDate)
    set the year of resultDate to (text 7 thru 10 of textDate)
    set the time of resultDate to 0

    if (length of textDate) > 10 then
        set the hours of resultDate to (text 12 thru 13 of textDate)
        set the minutes of resultDate to (text 15 thru 16 of textDate)

        if (length of textDate) > 16 then
            set the seconds of resultDate to (text 18 thru 19 of textDate)
        end if
    end if

    return resultDate
end convertDate


set myTimeDifResult to ((current date) - myWantedDate as string)
set daysV to myTimeDifResult / 86400
set hoursV to myTimeDifResult / 60 / 60
```

set hoursV to roundThis(hoursV, 2) --> -75.54
on roundThis(n, numDecimals)
    set x to 10 ^ numDecimals
    tell n * x
        if ((it mod 2) ^ 2 > 0.25) then return (it div 0.5 - it div 1) / x
        return it div 1 / x
    end tell
end roundThis

```
set final to hoursV

if hoursV > 24 then
    set final to (daysV as integer) - 1
end if


return final
```

update :

I figured out how two set both variable :

```
set the_decimalMin to hoursV mod 1
set the_decimaHours to hoursV div 1
```

but now I can't make the actual math :

```
set hoursV to the_decimaHours + (the_decimalMin / 60)
```

error :

> error "Can’t make the_decimalMin into type reference." number -1700
>   from MyMinutes to reference

Comment: Please make sure your code is indented properly — there is a section of code not within code formatting in the middle of your post, which makes the code hard to follow.

Comment: You can avoid a lot of your overcomplication by using integer and modulo math.  What kind of output are you trying to get - days, hours, minutes?

Comment: I’m trying to get the time difference between two date in days hours and minutes or hours / minutes only regarding the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AppleScript constants `days`, `hours`, and `minutes` are the number of seconds in a day, hour, and minute respectively, so you can just perform some modulo math to get the components.  For example, the hour would be the number `mod days div hours`, the minute would be the number `mod hours div minutes`, and the seconds would be the number `mod minutes`.

Putting all that together into a few general-purpose handlers would be something like:

```
set myVariableDateHere to "25/03/2019 00:00:00"
set myWantedDate to convertDate(myVariableDateHere)
log result
set difference to (current date) - myWantedDate
log result
log timeString(difference)
log formatTime(difference)

# Convert date text to an AppleScript date.
# format is DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss (time is optional)
to convertDate(dateText)
  set dateTemplate to (current date)
  tell dateTemplate to set {its day, its month, its year} to words 1 thru 3 of dateText
  set time of dateTemplate to 0
  tell words of dateText to if (count it) > 3 then set time of dateTemplate to (hours * (item 4)) + (minutes * (item 5)) + (item 6)
  return dateTemplate
end convertDate

# Return an elapsed time string from a number of seconds.
on timeString(theSeconds)
  if class of theSeconds is integer then set theSeconds to "" & ¬
    (theSeconds div days) & " days, " & ¬
    (theSeconds mod days div hours) & " hours, " & ¬
    (theSeconds mod hours div minutes) & " minutes, and " & ¬
    (theSeconds mod minutes) & " seconds"
  return theSeconds
end timeString

# Return a formatted time string from a number of seconds.
# format is hh:mm:ss (wraps at 24 hours)
to formatTime(theSeconds)
  if class of theSeconds is integer then tell "0" & ¬
    (10000 * (theSeconds mod days div hours) ¬
      + 100 * (theSeconds mod hours div minutes) ¬
      + (theSeconds mod minutes)) ¬
      to set theSeconds to (text -6 thru -5) & ":" & (text -4 thru -3) & ":" & (text -2 thru -1)
  return theSeconds
end formatTime
```